# Mouse Listener class

Tags: java, class, click, listener

I am trying to create a mouse listener class, simply for detecting mouse clicks. My code

```
package game.input;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Mouse implements MouseAdapter{

    public Mouse(Component c){
        c.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public boolean mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

is giving me two errors:

- "Interface expected here", pointing to the MouseAdapter
- "Method addMouseListener in class Component cannot be applied to given types", pointing to the c.addMouseListener(this)

How can I solve this two problems and accomplish the simple task of creating a detector for mouse clicks? This is the first time I write a MouseListener, so any other comments about mistakes I have done are welcome.

Comment: What do you think _Interface expected here_ means?

Comment: With all due respect, I do not know yet what is an Interface and how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`MouseAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) is a `class` not a `interface`, you need to use `extends` instead of `implements`

```
public class Mouse extends MouseAdapter{
```

Take a look at

- [What Is a Class?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)
- [What Is an Interface?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)
- [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

For more details

FYI...

```
public boolean mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
```

Will never be called, as it does not meet the requirements of the `MouseListener` interface contract, it should be...

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
```

Comment: Thanks again, MadProgrammer, answer will be accepted!

Comment: @gabzerbinato If you truly don't understand what an `interface` is, I suggest you go back to language basics for embarking on something as complex as a GUI - IMHO